# websocket not connecting to server

Tags: websocket, socket.io, render.com

created a separate client and server to train with a websocket, works locally, after deploying the server to render, the websocket does not connect

can someone tell me what i'm missing?

I tried to change the port, added transports: ['websocket'] to the connection settings, but it didn't work

[client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR8nE.jpg),
[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hjv2.jpg),

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
// const socket = io.connect('chat-server-avfu.onrender.com');
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('chat-message', (message) =>
    setMessages((state) => [...state, message])
  );
}, []);
```

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import Message from './models/chat.js';
const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat-message', async (message) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', message);
    try {
      await Message.create(message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
export default httpServer;
```